# Hibernate: Value too long for column

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

For a project I am working on, we use Spring Boot JPA with H2 database to store certain objects and information. However, after testing the application a bit, I got the following error:

```
2022-04-03 17:41:19 jdbc[3]: exception
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Value too long for column "LIST_OF_PLAYERS VARBINARY(255)": "X'aced0005737200136a6176612e7574696c2e41727261794c6973747881d21d99c7619d03000149000473697a6578700000000a77040000000a7372000e6a61... (262)"; SQL statement:
update lobby set host_id=?, is_public=?, is_started=?, list_of_players=?, token=? where id=? [22001-200]
```

So I figured that I had to change the maximum allowed number of characters and did the following:

```
@Column(name = "listOfPlayers", length = 10000)
public ArrayList<Long> playerIds;
```

It appears that the length attribute only works for VARCHAR and not for VARBINARY. Is it possible to set the maximum for VARBINARY too? If so how?